# AWS S3 rate limit and SlowDown errors

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, python-asyncio, boto

I'm refactoring a job that uploads ~1.2mln small files to AWS; previously this upload was made file by file on a 64 CPUs machine with processes. I switched to an async + multiprocess approach following [S3 rate limits and best practices](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/optimizing-performance.html) and [performance guidelines](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/optimizing-performance-guidelines.html) to make it faster. With sample data I can achieve execution times as low as 1/10th. With production loads S3 is returning "SlowDown" errors.

Actually the business logic makes the folder structure like this:

```
s3://bucket/this/will/not/change/<shard-key>/<items>
```

The objects will be equally splitted across ~30 shard-keys, making every prefix contain ~40k items.

We have every process writing on its own prefix and launching batches of 3k PUT requests in async until completion. There is a sleep after the batch write operation to ensure that we do not send another batch before 1.1sec has passed, so we will respect the 3500 PUT requests per second.

The problem is that we receive SlowDown errors for ~1 hour and then the job writes all the files in ~15 minutes. If we lower the limit to 1k/sec this gets even worse, running for hours and never finishing.

This is the distribution of the errors over time for the 3k/sec limit:
[image]

We are using Python 3.6 with [aiobotocore](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiobotocore) to run async.

Doing some sort of trial and error to try to understand how to mitigate this takes forever on production data and testing with a lower quantity of data gives us different results (flawlessly works).

Did I miss any documentation regarding how to make the system scale up correctly?

Comment: some code would help others identify the issue faster.

Comment: We found a bug in the code that may be the root cause of this problem, I'll try and check if it was it as soon as possible, then I will get back with an answer or some more details.

Comment: any updates? Can you share your code if possibe?

Comment: Unfortunately no good news and can't share the code. We weren't able to reach the higher possible limit, temporarily set it to a way lower one and then I changed my job after some time :(